# delete existing code from github repo and push fresh code without deleting the github repo

Tags: git, github

I have a existing github repo with previously pushed code. The thing is that currently i am working on a fresh project copy in my local computer which i have not configured for remote github repo.

So now i want to push the new copy in my local computer to the existing github repo. The problem is that once i add the remote existing github repo to my local project, i guess it will require me to first pull the repo before pushing it which will mess up my local code.

In my case, git clone want help as well so need help to solve this problem.

######## Additional info after few hours of posting this question: #########

To check if it allows me to push code to git hub, i created a new test project locally and added remote github URL and tried pushing the code. The result was as i expected, it asked me to pull first rather. so guys any solution? 
[image]

Comment: You can do first commit with your changes, add remote, fetch and rebase. That will put your commit on top of everything.

Comment: If you really don't care about the stuff already at github, and the repo is not shared with anyone yet, you can `git push --force`.

Comment: @JBNizet is there other way around without using force ?

Comment: fetch and rebase instead of pull, than push without force

Comment: @rajasimon I don't think so. Fetching and rebasing is very different, since it keeps the github commits in the history and rewrites the local commits on top of the remote ones (which might be what the OP wants, he didn't say).